# Erro ao tentar imprir o retorno de uma matriz bidimensional

Tags: c, funções, matriz

Eu estou tentando imprimir uma matriz bidimensional através em um laço `for` só que a matriz ela é retornada através de uma função que eu criei. Estou suspeitando que o erro deve se encontrar nela mas eu não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 2

int *retorna_matriz2D();

int mat2D[DIM][DIM];

int main(){
    int x, y;
    int *r = retorna_matriz2D(mat2D);
    for(x = 0; x < DIM; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < DIM; y++){
            printf("%d", r[x][y]); // LINHA 13
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int *retorna_matriz2D(int mat[][DIM]){
    int x, y;
    for(x = 0; x < DIM; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < DIM; y++){
            mat2D[x][y] = 2;
        }
    }
    for(x = 0; x < DIM; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < DIM; y++){
        printf("%d", mat[x][y]);
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return *mat;
}
```

o compilador aponta que tem um erro na linha 13 com a mensagem

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

supostamente indicando que o erro esta na linha do `printf()` mas eu não vejo nada de errado, onde estaria o erro deste código? outra coisa também é que o laço `for` dentro da função `retorna_matriz2D()` é executado mas o da minha função `main()` não, indicando que a minha matriz foi atribuída ao meu ponteiro `*r`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma coisa que eu costumo dizer é que códigos confusos que fazem mais do que deviam sempre dão margem para erros. Este é o caso. Este código pode ser enormemente simplificado e resolvido alguns outros problemas nem tão visíveis, e feito isto não há erro algum.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 2

void retorna_matriz2D(int mat[][DIM]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < DIM; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < DIM; y++) {
            mat[x][y] = 2;
            printf("%d\n", mat[x][y]);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int mat2D[DIM][DIM];
    retorna_matriz2D(mat2D);
    for (int x = 0; x < DIM; x++) for (int y = 0; y < DIM; y++) printf("%d\n", mat2D[x][y]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cxCCQy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jyxqnsjy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/IndexError.c).

Comment: Por quê os valores de mat2D é 2 sendo que você não os declarou? Nunca estudei C, mas eu pensava que sabia o básico só por ter aprendido C#. 

Comment: @bigown eu quero que a minha matriz seja atribuida a uma variavel no *r no meu caso e o laço for seja executado com base na matriz retornada, no seu exemplo a função retorna_matriz2D() não esta retornando nada

Comment: @Francisco não sei se entendi qual a dúvida, pode ter algo que você não entendeu, mas me parece que o código faz o óbvio e igual em todas linguagens normais

Comment: @Assanges Não retorna porque não precisa, era redundante e causava problemas. Não invente coisas desnecessárias no código, faça o simples que funciona melhor.

Comment: @bigown essa saída é possivel apenas com a função retorna_matriz2D() então não faria sentido, eu preciso que a matriz seja retornada para que eu possa usar ela fora da função.

Comment: @Assanges o que você está falando não faz sentido.

Comment: @Assanges , do jeito que está feito, as informações da matriz estão devidamente próprias para serem manipuladas. O que aconteceu é que a variável `mat2D` não foi modificada, mas sim o conteúdo que ele aponta, como efeito colateral da chamada à função `retorna_matriz2D`

Comment: @bigown por que não faz?

Comment: @Assanges você é que tem que dar sentido para o que está falando, não faz porque eu te mostrei que simplificando tudo funciona e é melhor, você quer complicar e deixar de funcionar, isso pra mim não faz sentido.

Comment: Realmente @bigown agora eu conseguir compreender o seu exemplo e esta bem mais simples o que acontece é que eu estava testando funções que retornam dados eu criei um array[4] de inteiros e conseguir retornar ele para uma *variável e depois ler através de um laço for mas essa minha matriz empenco não sei por que, tirando isso o seu exemplo esta bem mais simples e funcional obrigado!

Comment: @bigown olha aqui um exemplo de como eu implementei com um array https://ideone.com/vCFyth

Comment: Pra mim isto está errado, apesar de funcionar, mas você tem o direito de fazer como quiser, eu sempre vou ensinar o certo.

Answer (score 0):

Vejamos o tipo de `r`: `int*`. Isso significa que ele é apenas um ponteiro. Um simples é puro ponteiro.

Ponteiros, basicamente, tem duas operações:

1. Desreferenciamento (operador `*`), o que retorna o tipo apontado;
2. Aritmética de ponteiros/offset do ponteiro (operador `+`), o que retorna um ponteiro.

Existe também uma operação responsável por fazer o offset é o desreferenciamento: elemento no índice `i`. Essa operação é denotada por `[i]` e é equivalente a `*(ptr + i)`.

Quando você tenta fazer `r[i][j]`, vamos ver como cada operação é feita individualmente.

Inicialmente, `r[i]`.  Isso é equivalente a `*(r + i)`, portanto retornando um inteiro. Chamamos ele de `v`. Então, temos `r[i][j] == v[j]`. Porém `v` é do tipo referenciado por `r`, portanto um `int`. E inteiros não podem sofrer desreferenciamento direto.